# Can somebody tell me whom wins in this poker flush?

Tags: texas-hold-em, hand-reading

Which of the pictured hands would win?
Thanks[image]

Answer (score 12):

OK, so you have:

- Board: 3⋄ 9♠ A♠ 4♠ 8♠
- Player 1: Q♠ 9⋄
- Player 2: K♠ J⋄
- Player 3: Q♣ 5♠

Well, combining the 5 best cards, each player will have:

- Player 1: A flush: A♠ Q♠ 9♠ 8♠ 4♠
- Player 2: A flush: A♠ K♠ 9♠ 8♠ 4♠
- Player 3: A flush: A♠ 9♠ 8♠ 5♠ 4♠

Therefore the winner is player 2 because his King is bigger than player 1's Queen or player 3's five; therefore his flush is the best.

Comment: To all future people who see this: please don't upvote this answer anymore .... it's too trivial for so much reputation :) .

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. We are all kind of new to poker and have no much experience to know how details it work. Well,thanks for your fast answer.